# How to connect Python to SAP Business Objects?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, business-objects

I'm trying to fetch some data from SAP Business Objects 4.2 using Python/SqlAlchemy and convert it to a dataframe.
Only one problem, the script does not work and I get no errors except that Jupyter notebook restart Python's kernel.

Here is the code I'm using (ofc, I put my credentials and the table/columns names before running the script) :

#### CODE :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import hdbcli

engine = create_engine('hana+hdbcli://username:password@servername:port')

df= pd.read_sql('''
SELECT
  TABLE_A.COLUMN_1,
  TABLE_A.COLUMN_2,
FROM
  TABLE_A
WHERE
  COLUMN_1 = 'VALUE_X'
''', engine)

df
```

#### EDIT:

In Google Chrome, I use LDAP authentification to connect to SAP BO :

[image]

In Live Office (Excel add-in), I put my credentials and in the URL web service name, I put this : `http://servername:port/services/session`

[image]

Comment: are you sure your SAP BO runs on HANA? did you thoroughly re-check the connection settings (server, port)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HANA. I only have a login to SAP BO where there is a lot of universes/databases/tables and make some basic queries. Now, I'm wondering if I can access to these universes from Python. Btw, I edited my post. Can you check that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you use HANA dialect, maybe because you find it [here](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana), but it is wrong.

SAP BO has distributed architecture where different reports and universes may be located on different backend instances on multiple instances, may them be HANA or not, you never know. Look at the data tier at the bottom of the pic and you get the idea

[image]

Long story short, you cannot directly connect to SAP BO like you intends, and as far as I know SQLAlchemy has no out-of-the-box connector to BO.

There are third-parties like [Python Connector for SAP BusinessObjects](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sapbusinessobjectsbi-python-sqlalchemy.rst) from CData that allows connecting to SAP BO in a dialect-like straightforward manner, but they cost money.

```
engine = create_engine("sapbusinessobjectsbi:///?User=username&;Password=password&Url=http://myinstance:6405/biprws")
```